# AJAX Submit - Status 200 with error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I realise there are already questions about this, but none have been able to solve my problem.

I'm trying to submit a form in a Jquery Modal using AJAX, but it's not working despite saying status 200. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
    });

    $("#add-course").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });

    $("#btncancel").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
    });

    $('#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID%>').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var courseDetails = {};
        courseDetails.Code = $('#<%=addcode.ClientID%>').val();
        courseDetails.Name = $('#<%=addname.ClientID%>').val(); 

        var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            courseDetails: courseDetails
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("updatetest.aspx/addCourseSP") %>',
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnErrorCall,
        });

        function OnSuccess(response, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var result = response.d;
            if (result == "success") {
                $("#msg").html("Success");
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
            } else {
                $("#msg").html("jqXHR: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + " " + "AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        }

        function OnErrorCall() {
            $("#msg").html("error");
        }
    });
});
```

The code behind calls a stored procedure which I checked works. I've also checked the JSON string at jsonlint.com and it says it's valid.

I've checked using F12 in browser (Chrome/Firefox) which basically says the same thing, status 200 with d:"error". The JSON string is under Params, so I don't think that's the issue.

I've tried debugging using various different ways, right now it's returning jqXHR: "success" AJAX error: [object Object] : undefined. I'm not sure what else to try. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) shows the success callback as:

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

Doesn't match your parameter list

```
function OnSuccess(response, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

When you try to use this in your script, `textStatus` is not a string and `errorThrown` is *undefined*.

So the request succeeded (Status 200) but your script is generating the error after the response is returned to the client.

Comment: Thanks! I modified my function and I'm now getting this: 1) jqXHR {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"d\":\"error\"}","responseJSON":{"d":"error"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"} 2) text status: success 3) data: [object Object]

Comment: If you're asking why the status is still 200 it's because the framework considers the request successfully processed. If you're trying to trap business logic errors you'll need to explicitly change the return status or check for an error flag in your response `responseJSON`.

Answer (score -1):

your function contains the following line

```
 dataType: "json",
```

it means data returned must be correctly formatted json, if it not it will consider it error